# change the backgroud color of button when it is selected in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, button

I want to change the color of button when it is selected , using blackberry programming
by default its borders become red , I want to change its background color light gray when it is selected .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try custom buttons:

http://swati-blackberry.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-create-custom-button-field-in.html